# Required Smart Sync Latest Version

Tags: smartsync

I am using the below smartsync version in my native android project

com.salesforce.mobilesdk:SmartSync:5.0.0

I need to upgrade this to the latest version, let me know what is the latest version of the library and how to integrate the same documentation would be helpful on the same

Comment: 8.2 or 8.3 should be the latest

Comment: @zaitsman but when i try to use the same 8.2 or 8.3 it is not working up here failed to download the same

Comment: Where are you downloading it from?

Comment: @zaitsman  for android projects i will use this as an implementation and android studio tool will download the same